# Using FIRST_VALUE without including inner columns in group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, vertica

I am using a table that looks like this:

```
userID, eventDate, eventName
1  2019-01-01  buySoup
2  2019-01-01  buyEggs
2  2019-01-03  buyMilk
2  2019-01-04  buyMilk
3  2019-01-02  buyBread
3  2019-01-03  buyBread
```

My current query is:

```sql
SELECT
    userID,
    FIRST_VALUE(eventName) OVER (
        PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY eventDate ASC
    ) AS firstBought 
FROM table 
GROUP BY userID
```

I feel like this should return:

```
userID, firstBought
1  buySoup
2  buyEggs
3  buyBread
```

Instead, it gives the error:

> 'ERROR: Column "table.eventName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'

Is there a way to grab this value without including it in the group by function, or creating a sub query? I'm using PostgreSQL.

If I do include it in the group by clause, it returns

```
userID, firstBought
1  buySoup
2  buyEggs
2  buyEggs
2  buyEggs
3  buyBread
3  buyBread
```

I understand that I could make it a subquery and then group by userID, firstBought, but I'd rather not create another subquery.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `group by`, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct userID,
       FIRST_VALUE(eventName) over (partition by userID order by eventDate ASC) as firstBought 
from table ;
```

Or, you can use arrays:

```
select userId,
       (array_agg(eventName order by eventDate))[1] as firstBought
from table
group by userId;
```

Postgres doesn't have a "first" aggregation function, but this works pretty well.

Comment: Although that's useful, and works exactly as intended, my table actually also includes more columns, and my query includes max() and other aggregate functions on those columns. This means I do need the group by at the end. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Cyborgcanoe . . . This answer provides two solutions.  The second one uses `group by`.

Comment: thank you, the second answer is great. Unfortunately, I'm actualy using Vertica Analytic Database v9.1.1-5, a branch of postgres which doesn't include array_agg. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Cyborgcanoe . . . You should correctly tag your questions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` could do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid)
       userid, eventdate, eventname
FROM "table"
ORDER BY (eventdate);
```

This will give you the row per `userid` with the minimum `eventdate`.

Answer (score 2):

`FIRST_VALUE` is not an aggregate function. It is an analytic window function. So your base query does not need a `GROUP BY` clause. It should be re-written as:

```sql
SELECT 
        userID,
        FIRST_VALUE(eventName) over (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY eventDate ASC) AS firstBought
FROM table;
```

From one of your above comments it sounds like there are other functions that you are using including aggregate functions like `MAX`. To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need to use the above query as a subquery. This will allow you to use aggregate functions and get unique values from your base query. The query can look something like this (I added a price column as an example).

```sql
SELECT userID, firstBought, MAX(price)
FROM (
        SELECT userID, price, FIRST_VALUE(eventName) over (partition by userID order by eventDate ASC) as firstBought 
        from test
) x
GROUP BY userId, firstBought;
```

This should do the trick! You can use other aggregate functions on the outside query and an additional window functions in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with  A. Saunders.

You need an outside query.

With the exception of SELECT DISTINCT , which actually boils down to a GROUP BY all columns of the SELECT list, you can't mix OLAP and GROUP BY functions into the same SELECT.

So , if you do have MAX(), you have to:

```
WITH -- your input data ...
input(userID,eventDate,eventName) AS (
          SELECT 1,DATE '2019-01-01','buySoup'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2019-01-01','buyEggs'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2019-01-03','buyMilk'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2019-01-04','buyMilk'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2019-01-02','buyBread'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2019-01-03','buyBread'
)
,
getfirstbought AS (
  SELECT 
    userid
  , eventdate
  , FIRST_VALUE(eventname) OVER (
      PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY eventdate
   ) AS firstbought
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  userid
, firstbought
, MAX(eventdate) AS maxdt
FROM getfirstbought
GROUP BY 1,2;
-- out  userid | firstbought |   maxdt    
-- out --------+-------------+------------
-- out       2 | buyEggs     | 2019-01-04
-- out       3 | buyBread    | 2019-01-03
-- out       1 | buySoup     | 2019-01-01
-- out (3 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (3 rows): 22.157 ms. All rows formatted: 22.208 ms
```